# How do I elevate the priority of a process without giving that process superuser rights?

Tags: linux, sudo, nice

I have a high priority service that I start with `sudo nice -n -10 process`. This process does not need superuser rights though, except for the priority elevation. But nice requires superuser privileges to elevate priority.

How do I run a process with elevated priority, without also running it as root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `/etc/security/limits.conf`. There you can specify which priorities that users or groups are allowed to use. Manual page: `man 5 limits.conf`

Comment: Thank you kindly. I can set the minimum priority for the user to -10, and skip using sudo completely.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is this (which I just thought of after asking):

`sudo nice -10 sudo -u user command`

But it seems like there should be a more elegant method.

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is using `sudo renice` to change the process's priority after starting it. To obtain the process's PID, you can use `ps` and `sed`, or you can start it in background and get its process directly from the shell:

```
process &
pid=$!
sudo renice -10 $pid
fg $pid                 # if you don't want it in background
```

Note that if the process spawns other processes and exits, it'll probably have done so by the time renice runs, so you'll want to use `ps` to get the PID of the child process/processes instead, and renice those.

Comment: This would work, but I think it's even more awkward than the answer I gave (`sudo nice -10 sudo -u user command`)

Comment: However this answer doesn't mess with the environment like `sudo` does. For instance, `sudo` will reset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` even with `-E`.

Comment: Also note that `fg` can only be used directly from an interactive shell; you need to use `wait` instead for scripts.